# Magento Product Upload Images not Appearing .Net

Tags: c#, .net, magento, soap

I have an internal Product object and a Magento product , I am trying to upload an image to the Magento product , but even though the image is uploaded , it is not set as a thumbnail for the product , here is my code :

```
    private catalogProductAttributeMediaCreateEntity CreateProductImage(Product product)
    {
        var productImageEntitiyInternal = new catalogProductImageFileEntity();
        productImageEntitiyInternal.content = product.Image;
        productImageEntitiyInternal.mime = product.ImageMime;

        var productImageEntity = new catalogProductAttributeMediaCreateEntity();
        productImageEntity.file = productImageEntitiyInternal;
        productImageEntity.types = new[] { "thumbnail", "small_image", "image" }; ;
        productImageEntity.position = "0";
        productImageEntity.exclude = "0";
        return productImageEntity;
    }
```

and then

```
string imageFileName = _proxy.catalogProductAttributeMediaCreate(_sessionId, magentoProduct.SKU, magentoProduct.Image, "default", null);
```

Where magentoProduct.image is the entity I just created .

The image is uploaded but not set as the prodcut's thumbnail image.

Answer (score 1):

I have a little bit of knowledge of magento.I have seen without flashplayer we cannot upload any image also show the image properly.So if you have not installed flashplayer so at first installed it and try it.